# destroy method of jquery-ui-rotatable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have downloaded jquery-ui- rotatable plugin from the link: https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-UI-Rotatable-Elements.html . The destroy method of it doesn't seem to have defined or is not working. I am new at it would like to use it like the jquery-ui draggable and resizable. In draggable it is like $('selector').draggable('destroy'). Similarly for resizable it is $('selector').resizable('destroy'). Need the same way out to destroy, enable and disable in rotatable. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It may help

```
ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", false);
```